# SwiftUIのList内の表示が、スクロールによってずれてしまう

Tags: swiftui

Qiita APIを使って記事一覧（タイトル、日時、タグ）を表示するアプリを作成しているのですが、スクロールするとタグの表示がズレるという現象に悩んでいます。
おそらく、Listにてタグをforeachの繰り返しで表示していることが原因なのかなと考えています。（繰り返しが終了する前にスクロールされてる？）
どなたかこちらの解決策をご教授いただければ助かります。

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(networkManager.posts) { post in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: post.url)) {
                        VStack {
                            Text(post.title)
                                .font(.callout)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName:"tag")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 13.0, height: 13.0, alignment: .leading)
                                
                                // 以下タグ表示の処理
                                ForEach(0..<post.tags.count) { i in
                                    if let tag = post.tags[i].name {
                                        Text(tag)
                                            .font(.caption)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text("更新日：")
                                Text(post.updated_at.prefix(10))
                            }
                            .font(.caption)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("MyQiita"))
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.networkManager.fetchData(searchWord: "")
        })
    }
    
    //MARK: - navigationBarの色設定
    init() {
        setupNavigationBar()
    }
    
    func setupNavigationBar() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

NetworkManager.swift

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var posts = [Results]()
    
    func fetchData(searchWord: String) {
        let urlString = "https://qiita.com/api/v2/items?page=1&per_page=20&query=tag%3A" + searchWord
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode([Results].self, from: safeData) // 戻り値の型は第一引数によって決まる
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error(data):\(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

PostData.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let updated_at: String
    let url: String
    let tags: [Tags]
}

struct Tags: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `NetworkManager`のコード(特に`posts`に関連する全データ型のコード)を示すことはできますか? 例えば「`Identifiable`への適合のさせ方がおかしい」と言った場合、記述されているような事象が起こり得ます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。network関連のコードを追記いたしましたので、ご確認いただきたく存じます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: コードの追記ありがとうございます。コードにもサーバから送られてくるデータにも特段おかしな点は見当たらないので、何らかのSwiftUIのバグを踏み抜いている可能性がありますね。もう少し調べさせてください。

Comment: 手元で全く同じ事象が再現できない(別の事象が発生してクラッシュする)ので、確実なことが言える状態ではないんですが、`ForEach(0..<post.tags.count)`の代わりに`ForEach(post.tags.indices, id: \.self)`として見るとどうなりますか?

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。コメント頂いた通り修正すると、ズレが見られなくなりました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございました。こちらでは確認できなかったので、コメントで失礼しましたが、できれば自己回答を投稿してみてください。(少し間を置かないといけないかもしれませんが、承認もお願いします。) SwiftUIでは、ドキュメントもノウハウの蓄積もまだまだといった実情ですので、多くの方の役に立つ情報だと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 手元で全く同じ事象が再現できない(別の事象が発生してクラッシュする)ので、確実なことが言える状態ではないんですが、ForEach(0..<post.tags.count)の代わりにForEach(post.tags.indices, id: .self)として見るとどうなりますか?

指摘いただいた部分を以下のように修正することで解決できました。

```
ForEach(post.tags.indices, id: \.self) { i in
 if let tag = post.tags[i].name {
  Text(tag)
   .font(.caption)
 }
}
```

List内でForEach処理をする場合はarrayでもインデックスを利用した方が良いみたいです。